# Download tax return before filing to show to accountant

Tags: united-states, income-tax, turbotax

I like using turbotax to gather my information, but I'd like to work with my tax advisor to review what I'm filing before actually submitting the return. Is there a way for me to show my tax advisor what I've plugged into the system without me signing into the system for him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using TurboTax Online.  You can have [TurboTax Online print your return to a PDF file](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/1914214-can-i-print-a-copy-of-my-turbotax-online-return-before-i-file-it), which you can then show to whoever you want to look it over for you.  It looks like TurboTax Online requires you to pay the TurboTax fees, if you haven't already, before it will let you print.